# JS- Math.atan(y/x) with x==0

Tags: javascript, math

I want to determine an angle by xValue and yValue, but if xValue is Zero I does not work. What shall I do in that case?

```
Math.atan(yValue/xValue);
```

Comment: If `xValue` is zero than you divide by zero, which is an error.  What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I just ran `Math.atan(1/0)` and it returned `pi/2` just like it should. Similarly, `Math.atan(-1/0)` returned `-pi/2` JavaScript uses floats and has basic concepts of infinity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding angles 0-360](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707151/finding-angles-0-360). You may have noticed that your code also gives the wrong answer if `yValue=0` and `xValue=-1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Math.atan2(y,x)`;

Math.atan2(1,0)

Result:

> 1.5707963267948966

Comment: The '2' stands for the two parameters.