# How to calculate degree between two line with integer values (not vectors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm working on small effect animation where it creates 5 distinctive objects expanding in 5 different directions from the center. The objects should not stack on each other so i'm thinking about distributing them in separated angles of circle but i don't know how to calculate the angle between two randomly created lengths of lines in px (for example: 100px line and 50px line)

Here is my code:

```
//Container of the objects
var box =  $('.nodebox')
box.css({
height: box.width(),
top: (($(window).height() - box.width())/2),
})
//Main object in the center, one click on this, it will disappear followed by the activation of 5 sub-objects animation.
var Ndd = $('.Node');
Ndd.css({
top: ((box.width()-Ndd.width())/2),
left:((box.height()-Ndd.height())/2)
})
//Randomly creating the sub-objects
function createNnodes(n){
var nodeArrays = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< n ; i++){
        var smNd = $('<div class="smallNodes"></div>');
        if (!$('body').data('mobile')){ //check to see if the device is mobile or not
        var widthn = (Math.random()*($(window).width()*0.04) + $(window).width()*0.01);
        } else {
        var widthn = (Math.random()*($(window).width()*0.1) + $(window).width()*0.04);
        };
        var heightn = widthn; //making sure the objects are square-shaped
        smNd.css({width: widthn, height: heightn})
        nodeArray.push(smNd);
    }
return nodeArrays;
}

//Handling the animation 
function animateNodes(){
var nodeArray = createNnodes(6);
//creating 2 random distances for each object so that it tralvels diagonally or horizontally or vertically
for (var i = 0; i < nodeArray.length; i++){
  var distance1 = ((Math.random()*Ndd.width()) + Ndd.width()*0.5);
  var distance2 = ((Math.random()*Ndd.width()) + Ndd.width()*0.5);
        //Create random "+" or "-" 
        function Pornot() {
           if(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)){
              return '+=';
           }else {
              return '-=';
           }
        }
  var plusornot1 = Pornot();
  var plusornot2 = Pornot();
  $(nodeArray[i]).css({
      top:((box.height()-$(nodeArray[i]).width())/2),
      left:((box.width()-$(nodeArray[i]).width())/2)
  }).appendTo('.nodebox').animate({
      left: plusornot1 + distance1,
      top: plusornot2 + distance2,
      opacity:0,
    },2000,function(){
           $(nodeArray[i]).remove();
    })
}
```

}

The code above works just fine, what my only concern is, again, how to specify the angle between distance1 and distance2...

A picture to demonstrate:
[Click to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfteV.jpg)

Upon clicking on screen the main node will disappear. After that, 5 smaller instances of the node are created behind it and they synchronously move away from the center in 5 different angles.

Comment: Could you provide a picture? Question is not clear, you are using non-trivial terminology.

Comment: OK, I see the picture. And what is an angle to measure? Between what objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding angles 0-360](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707151/finding-angles-0-360)

Comment: @MBo its the angle between line 1 and 2 for example( i don't knue, degree between them ?), i want the sub-objects to be bursted from the center like  fireworks or sth.... my code inside the function animateNodes() handles the translating animation of each sub-object base on distance1 and distance2. As the result, they can move horizontally, vertically or dianogally (likewise, the value of top: 100px and left: -200px will make one node to move up dianogally from right to left, what bugging me is the angle between that line and  x-axis....)

Comment: @user5542121 is there any other method to calculate the angle based on two provided line with their length? like between a 100px line and a 200px line. I have come accross those answer you provided and it seem to be not the one that i'm looking for.... Oh btw, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center point coordinates: (xc, yc)
First point coordinates: (x1, y1)
Second point coordinates: (x2, y2)
Angle between line segments (xc, yc)-(x1, y1) and (xc, yc)-(x2, y2):

```
dx1 = x1 - xc
dx2 = x2 - xc
dy1 = y1 - yc
dy2 = y2 - yc
len1  = Sqrt(dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1)
len2  = Sqrt(dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2)

Angle = ArcCos((dx1 * dx2 + dy1 * dy2) / (len1 * len2))
```

Comment: aw... i guess that's pretty much the only option involving in x,y,z and some other anonymous variables that seems unfamilliar, thanks for the help @MBo